# Reduce and preview image from base64 image string

Tags: php

I have loaded data from ajax data table using php. The problem is that data table load too much for base64 image string.

Can I reduce and direct preview base64 image?

```
 CONCAT('<img src=\"', profile, '\" class=\"img-thumbnail\" />') AS profile
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please, read the [ask] page and update your question.

Comment: You can save a preview image and use it instead. Or you don't save the image in the database at all and use a direct link instead.